# MongoDB: how can I split a collection in n collections?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

How can I split a generic collection in n collections?

It doesn't matter if it is not an exact method, this is, if the target collection has 1000 documents and `n=2` I don't care if one collection has 501 documents and the other one 499.

Comment: Do you need EXACTLY n collections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a straightforward unelegant way in a script you could run from the command line, e.g. `mongo --host yourhost thisScript.js`:

```
target = 3;

max = db.foo.count();

approx = Math.ceil(max / target);

n = 0;
i = 0;
c = db.foo.find();
while(c.hasNext()) {
    d = c.next();
    if(0 == i % approx) {
      n++;
    }
    i++;
    db['foo_'+n].insert(d);
}
```

A little more complicated but significantly faster: use bulk ops:

```
target = 3;

max = db.foo.count();

approx = Math.ceil(max / target);

n = 0;
i = 0;
bulk = null;
c = db.foo.find();
while(c.hasNext()) {
    d = c.next();
    if(0 == i % approx) {
        if(bulk != null) {
           bulk.execute();
        }
        n++;
        bulk = db['foo_'+n].initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    }
    i++;
    bulk.insert(d);
}
if(bulk != null) {
    bulk.execute();
}
```

Comment: @italktothewind  True, so I enhanced answer to use bulk ops which should give you a nice performance boost.